# Matlab: FFT and FRF gives peaks at different frequencies?

Tags: matlab, fft

I'm trying to make a fft from a transient time measurement but it seems that peaks are located at different locations than the measured FRF? The program (PULSE) I'm using have given me an averaged FRF and the transient signal is the last measurement of this series.

The fft of the transient acceleration signal is made by the following code:

```
% loading data:
[DataST, InfoST, errmsgST]=readuff('.\steel_tight_bolt_acc_center.uff');

dt=1.52588e-05; % sampling time
Fs=1/dt/2.56; % sampling frequency
NFFT = 2^nextpow2(length(DataST{1,5}.x)); % Next power of 2 from length signal
f = Fs*linspace(0,1,NFFT/2+1); % frequency 
figure 
subplot(2,1,1) 
plot(DataST{1,7}.x,abs(DataST{1,7}.measData)) % FRF data from PULSE
title(DataST{1,7}.d1) 


subplot(2,1,2)
L=length(DataST{1,5}.x);        % length of signal
a=DataST{1,5}.measData;         % Transient data measured [m/s^2]
A=2*abs(fft(a/L));              % calculating the fft
plot(f,A(1:(length(A))/2+1))
ylabel('2*|fft(Y)/N|')
title('FFT')
```

But by the resulting plot it seems that the peaks are located at different locations?
[image]

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you divide your sampling frequency by 2.56? This seems to be the source of the error.

Comment: Ahh. Just a stupid mistake because i knew that the PULSE program were using a sampling rate of 2.56 and therefore i expected that this should be the same. Thanks for the answer!